# Insert elements from array to table in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a js file called reservations.js, in this file I have an array of reservations, like:

```
var reservations = [
  { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "0166977", "Guest Name": "Jonny", "Room": null, "Type": "SUIT", "Rooms": "1", "Board": "BB", "Status": "IH", "Pax": "2,0,0,0", "Arrival": "07/08/12", "Departure": "09/08/12", "AgentDesc": "FIT", "AgentCode": "FIT", "Group": null, "Balance": "0", "Requests": "", "Remarks": null, "Fit/Group": "FIT", "ReturnGuestName": "", "StatusColor": "LightCoral" },
  { "HotelId": "01", "HotelName": "SPA", "ReservNum": "H000192", "Guest Name": null, "Room": null, "Type": "Folio", "Rooms": "0", "Board": "", "Status": "IH", "Pax": "0,0,0,0", "Arrival": "07/08/12", "Departure": "10/09/12", "AgentDesc": "movies", "AgentCode": "001", "Group": null, "Balance": "0", "Requests": "", "Remarks": "", "Fit/Group": "FIT", "ReturnGuestName": "", "StatusColor": "LightCoral" }
];
```

What I need to do is to create a table(in html) with 6 colomns: Res. Number, Guest Name, Status, Arrival Date, Departure Date, Room Type.
and insert the element from the array into the matching col in the table.

> Example: ReservNum": "0166977", So the number 0166977 will be in the
>   first col Res. Number.

My table is like this:

```
<table id="reservations">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Res. Number</th><th>Guest Name</th><th>Status</th><th>Arrival Date</th><th>Departure Date</th><th>Room Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>resnum</td><td>guestname</td><td>status</td><td>arrivaldate</td><td>departuredate</td><td>roomtype</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I don't know what how to do it.
I have try to do somthing like this in the js file:

```
$('#reservations tr').each(function (i) {
    $(this).find('td').html(reservations[i]);
});
```

But it is not working. (Maybe my html table is wrong or the js, or even both of them).

I'm new in js/jquery so I'm a little unsure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like below (***[Check the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FunvZ/1/)***):

```
var tbody = $('#reservations tbody'),
    props = ["ReservNum", "Guest Name", "Status", "Arrival", "Departure", "Type"];
$.each(reservations, function(i, reservation) {
  var tr = $('<tr>');
  $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
    $('<td>').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);  
  });
  tbody.append(tr);
});
```

Comment: In the demo it look good, but it's doesn't work in my project
(I'm working on microsoft visual web developer 2010 express)

Comment: This is my project:
The js file is:
    http://tinypic.com/r/f0tmt/6
The html is:
    http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2rxv5at&s=6
But what I see on screen is this:
    http://tinypic.com/r/nbf9mo/6

Maybe i'm missing out somthing in here..


Thank you very much!!

Comment: I have notice that the same thing is happen in the demo if I change it to javascript 1.7.
maybe this is my problem.
Do you have a solution for my question in js1.7?
Thank you.

Comment: OK I have managed, the problem was that I need this line in the begining of the js file:
$(document).ready(
function ()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if is this that you want but there is [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). It can receive JSON and make a grid.

Or You can also use this simple project on Github : [Json-To-HTML-Table](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Or you can also make your own using jQuery will make this simpler.

The following will take an array of arrays and store convert them into rows and cells.

```
$.getJSON(url , function(data) {
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                 
    })
    $("#target_table_id tbody").html(tbl_body);
});
```

You could add a check for the keys you want to exclude by adding something like

```
var expected_keys = { key_1 : true, key_2 : true, key_3 : false, key_4 : true };
```

at the start of the getJSON cbf and adding

```
if ( ( k in expected_keys ) && expected_keys[k] ) {
...
}
```

around the tbl_row += line.

Comment: Thanks @Zaheer It really helped me and works fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('#reservations tr').each(function (i) {
   var td = $(this).find('td');
   td.html(reservations[i]['ReservNum']);
   td = td.next();
   td.html(reservations[i]['Guest Name']);
   td = td.next();
   td.html(reservations[i]['Status']);
   td = td.next();
   td.html(reservations[i]['Arrival']);
   td = td.next();
   td.html(reservations[i]['Departure']);
   td = td.next();
   td.html(reservations[i]['Type']);
   td = td.next();
   td.html(reservations[i]['Rooms']);
   td = td.next();
   td.html(reservations[i]['Board']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [jquery.tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) method.

In HTML

```
<script id="template-table" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr>
            <th>Res. Number</th><th>Guest Name</th><th>Status</th><th>${Arrival}</th><th>${Departure}</th><th>Room Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>${ReservNum}</td><td>${Guest_Name}</td><td>${Status}</td><td>arrivaldate</td><td>departuredate</td><td>${Type}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</script>
```

In JS:

```
var reservations = [...];
$("#template-table").tmpl(reservations);
```