# Adding Arrays inside a table tag with JavaScript (schedule)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, schedule

I am really new to JavaScript so I am sorry about any misunderstanding in advance.  I have some arrays but I don't have any idea how to put them in a table in the order I want.

I want the first column to be filled with the day hours, and every other with the day of the week. The second column always need to be the current day, the other cells need to be empty. Here is the code so far:

```
function GetDates(startDate, daysToAdd) {
    var aryDates = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= daysToAdd; i++) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
        aryDates.push(DayAsString(currentDate.getDay()) + ", " + currentDate.getDate() + " " + MonthAsString(currentDate.getMonth()) + " " + currentDate.getFullYear());
    }

    return aryDates;
}

function MonthAsString(monthIndex) {
    var d = new Date();
    var month = new Array();
    month[0] = "January";
    month[1] = "February";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "October";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "December";

    return month[monthIndex];
}

function DayAsString(dayIndex) {
    var weekdays = new Array(6);
    weekdays[0] = "Sunday";
    weekdays[1] = "Monday";
    weekdays[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekdays[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekdays[4] = "Thursday";
    weekdays[5] = "Friday";
    weekdays[6] = "Saturday";

    return weekdays[dayIndex];
}

var dayHours = ['08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', ]
var startDate = new Date();
var aryDates = GetDates(startDate, 7);

$('#example').html(aryDates);
```

Comment: *"`and every other with the day of the week`"* what *other*? can you please elaborate? ... A "picture" of the desired result would be helpful

Comment: can you post a desired output?.. might help figuring out what u mean..

Comment: As an aside, an easier (and generally considered best-practice) way to create and populate those arrays is `var month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "etc."];` (with or without linebreaks after each comma, depending on what you find more readable). Which apparently you already know given that's how you do `dayHours`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the desired HTML elements directly in JavaScript, since there is no routine for this.

At the beginning of your **loop** you create a table row like this:

```
var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
```

Then you add your cells to that row similiar to this:

```
var $td = $('<td>' + value + '</td>')
$tr.append($td);
```

You have to do this for every column you want to be shown – (just replace `value` with the value you want). So you create a new cell, append it to the table row `$tr`. In the end of that loop you append this `$tr` to your table.

```
$('#example').append($tr);
```

Assumed that your table has the id example.

To achieve what's in your image:

**First:** Create Table Row, Loop over Dates in which you create Table Cells, Append To Table Row, Append to Table

```
var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
$tr.append($('<td>hours</td>'));
aryDates.forEach(function(date) {
  var $td = $('<td>' + date + '</td>');
  $tr.append($td);
});
$('#example').append($tr);
```

**Second:** Loop over hours, create td, append it to tr, and inside that loop, create another with the number of empty cells you want, and just append always an empty td to that table row, after all you append it to the table

```
dayHours.forEach(function(hour) {
  var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
  var $td = $('<td>' + hour + '</td>');
  $tr.append($td);
  for(var i = 0; i < aryDates.length; i++) {
    $tr.append('<td></td>');
  } 
  $('#example').append($tr);
});
```

Similar questions that could help you are:

[insert elements from array to table in jquery/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009810/insert-elements-from-array-to-table-in-jquery-js)

[Populate table from array using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322823/populate-table-from-array-using-jquery)

Alternatively you could check out frameworks like **Angular** or **React.js** that auto-update the DOM.

Comment: @rokocbuljan  I mean every first row of the next column to be populated with a day of the week . Here is example what I am trying to achieve . 

[IMG](http://i.imgur.com/tOAOq9o.jpg?1)

Comment: @ XDProgrammer here is a example [image](http://i.imgur.com/tOAOq9o.jpg?1)

Comment: It is just the same. You first create a table row, loop over your days of the week. And append that row to your table. And in another loop you go for the hours. If one column cell needs to be empty just append ``$('<td></td>')`` to the table row.

Comment: Hello folks . Thank you for the quick replies  and your time for helping me. @scientiaetveeritas  thank you for your code it helped me a lot and I learned from it much. I guess i should not rush with the coding and spend a little more of my time reading the documentations first :)  

Best regards

Comment: Hi @NickN. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark on the left. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I have another question. The idea is calling a pop up window where user enters Name and Last name, after clicking a <td>. Somehow I have found solution for that. However the problem is how to append the data in the clicked <td>. The snippet so far on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zcj3ab8/1/)

Comment: Actually this is a new question which deserves a new formal question on stackoverflow. So I will only explain it in short. Every function creates a new scope with new ``this``. So in the dblclick event handler you have access to the td. But in your click event handler it's the save button. You have to save the outer this like: var self = this; and then you can append it to $(self) in the click event handler.